80s/90s film reminiscent of "Payback," where a tortured man escapes and detonates a hotel bomb
I'm looking for an '80s or '90s movie where a guy gets beat up, tortured, and has some fingers cut off by some guys in a garage, then they throw him in a trunk. He tears through the back seat and gets in the car. He makes a phone call to a room in a hotel where he knows these guys are headed. The phone call triggers a bomb, killing the guys.
I thought it was Payback (1999) with Mel Gibson, but that’s not it. Anyone?

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Evil_That_Men_Do_(film) this has similar tropes

I know you've said that it's not Payback, but you're almost perfectly describing it. The torture scene, the escape through the seat of the car, the bomb triggered by a phone call, etc. are all close matches.

"Bronson, Fairfax, and their men drive to the address, Porter's apartment, with Porter locked in the trunk. As they go inside, Porter breaks free and uses the car phone to dial his apartment phone; Bronson answers, triggering the bomb left by Carter's men, and the explosion kills Bronson, Fairfax, and their men. Leaving Johnny cuffed to her radiator, Rosie joins Porter in starting a new life together, beginning by "going for breakfast...in Canada."

The torture scene.



The car boot scene is at 1:33:51 in the full movie.




Thanks! I wonder if it was edited out of my version. I’ll go back and watch it again!

Apparently there’s 3 or 4 versions. I just picked the wrong one. ‍♂️
